# Difficulty understanding discrete dynamical systems problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

I'm learning discrete dynamical systems right now in linear algebra and I am running up against an error in one particular problem that I can't seem to solve.

Problem:

Let x(t) = $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1(t)\\
    x_2(t)\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ be the solution to a discrete dynamical system:

$x_1(t+1)=10x_1(t)+4x_2(t)$

$x_2(t+1)=−8x_1(t)−2x_2(t)$

If x(0) =$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    5 \\
    -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$.

Put the eigenvalues in ascending order when you enter $x_1(t), x_2(t)$ below:

So far I have found the eigenvalues, but an struggling to find the constants for the equations(as represented by "(blank)". Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer so Far:

$x_1=(blank)(2)^t+(blank)(6)^t$

$x_2=(blank)(2)^t+(blank)(6)^t$

Comment: You set t=0 and solve for the unknown constants by plugging the solution into the initial conditions: x(t=0) = ....

Comment: But you are confused because you havent solved for the eigenvectors yet. Once you do, you will have two equations for two unknowns, not four unknowns as you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 10 & 4 \\
 -8 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \
Q = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \ \Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

we have

$$
x_{k+1} = Q\cdot\Lambda\cdot Q^{-1}x_k,\ \ \ M = Q\cdot\Lambda\cdot Q^{-1}
$$

or

$$
Q^{-1}x_{k+1} = \Lambda\cdot Q^{-1}x_k
$$

or

$$
X_{k+1} = \Lambda\cdot X_k
$$

with solution

$$
X_k = \Lambda^{k-1}X_0
$$

and finally

$$
x_k = Q\cdot \Lambda^{k-1}Q^{-1}x_0
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have difficulties with the eigenvector approach, you can also just simply compute $x(1)=\begin{bmatrix}38\\-34\end{bmatrix}$ and solve the two systems
$$
5=a_1+a_2\\
38=2a_1+6a_2
$$
for the coefficients of the $x_1$ component and
$$
-3=b_1+b_2\\
-34=2b_1+6b_2
$$
for the $x_2$ component.